# json ObjectForKey New Line

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Problem: The `UIAlertView` show `\n`instead break a line, from a Json response.

---

Json Response:

```
{"error":"Line 1.\\nLine 2."}
```

Code

```
[self setLastError:[dictJsonResult jsonObjectForKey:@"error"]];

UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration Failed"
    message:[ParseHelper lastError] delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Ismael already explained what's wrong; I tell you how to fix it:

```
[self setLastError:[[dictJsonResult jsonObjectForKey:@"error"]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\\` translates to `\` and it takes precedence because it comes first.

To explain a little further

`ABC\\nDEF` looks like:

```
ABC\nDEF
```

`ABC\nDEF` looks like:

```
ABC
DEF
```